# Automator: how to obtain the filename from a Finder object or from Variable

Tags: applescript, automator

This should be easy.

Our company has filenames that use this format:  yyyymmdd.brand.customername.pics

**Objective**: for each FILE, create a new FOLDER with the same name, without the file extension.

**Example** of automation objective:
Source File: 20210301.ABC.Jones.pics (file)
Target Result: 20210301.ABC.Jones (folder)

I've been trying unsuccessfully to obtain the name of the source file that excludes the path.

My automation is a folder action (here are the pertinent steps)

1. When file dropped into a specific folder, set variable TPEPathname = the filename (with path)
2. Get the value of variable TPEPathname from Step 1, pass the value into the next step.
3. Obtain a reference to the file using Get Selected Finder Items, pass the reference to the Finder object into the next step
4. Run AppleScript to obtain the name of the Finder object filename EXCLUDING THE PATH (see attached photo for the AppleScript)

Step 3 is successful.  Step 4 returns nothing. (ignore fileNamex)

I also tried to change the sequence by passing in the TPEPathname directly into the AppleScript, instead of passing in the Finder object.  Same result - Step 3 is successful, Step 4 returns nothing.

**Questions**:
Am I referencing the Step 3 Finder object correctly as an INPUT or PARAMETER within the AppleScript?  The value of "Input" seems to be null.  I don't see documentation on how to pass in or reference AppleScript parameters.

Will the function "fileName" in the AppleScript actually obtain and parse the filename without the path, or will the additional periods in the filename cause a problem?  Acceptable result will be either:
yyyymmdd.brand.customername OR yyyymmdd.brand.customername.pics

[image]

Comment: `input` is a list of alias specifiers. At least you need a loop for process each file separately. Apart from that an alias does not respond to `fileName`. And you are going to display `fileName` rather than `fileNamex`. So there are 3 syntax errors.

Comment: There is only one file being passed into the AppleScript at a time; looping not needed.  If I'm passing in a alias, what should I pass in instead, or what function should I use to extract the name from the alias?  I've displayed fileName to verify it is NULL, so this is not an actual syntax error - its a revision intended for testing: both fileName and fileNameX are NULL (and I've indicated above to ignore fileNameX)

Comment: Regardless how many files are selected `Get Finder Items` passes **always** a list of alias specifiers to the next action (or an empty list). You can get the file name from an alias only with the `Finder` or `System Events`. Already the first line `display dialog input` is a syntax error. The direct parameter must be `text`.

Comment: Got it.  Where's the reference docs that explain any of this?

Answer (score 0):

If I've read your OP correctly, your want to use a **Folder Action** which when a *file* is dropped,  a *folder* based on the *name* of the *file* without the *extension* is created in the *folder* assigned to the **Folder Action**, and then move the dropped *file* into the *folder* created of its *name*.

If that is all you are trying to do, then the following **Folder Action** using a **Run Shell Script** *action* with **Pass input: [as arguments]** does exactly that. There is no need to complicate things!

In other words, you drop a *file* name, e.g., **20210301.ABC.Jones.pics** on the *folder* the **Folder Action** is attached to and a *folder* named **20210301.ABC.Jones** is created in the *folder* the **Folder Action** is attached to, then **20210301.ABC.Jones.pics** *file* is moved into the **20210301.ABC.Jones** *folder*.

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
    # f  = fully qualified pathname
    # d  = directory pathname
    # fn = filename with extension
    # n  = filename without extension

for f in "$@"; do
    [ -f "${f}" ] || continue
    d="${f%/*}"
    fn="${f##*/}"
    n="${fn%.*}"
    cd "${d}" || exit
    [ ! -d "${n}" ] && mkdir "${n}"
    mv -n "${f}" "${n}"
done
```

---

[image]

---

**Notes**:

- The `-n` *option* used in the `mv` *command* stops from overwriting an existing *file*. If you have a scenario where you want existing *files* overwritten, then remove the `-n` *option* used in the `mv` *command*.
- The *shell script* as coded can handle multiple *files* dropped at the same time or just one *file* at a time.

Comment: Looks awesome on paper - but does nothing.  Also, it is possible to return a value back to my Automator Script?  The next step is to obtain the contents of the FILE (show package contents) and put them into the new FOLDER.  To do that, I'll need handles to the source and destination.

Comment: Also - I'm on Big Sur.  Privacy Model problem?  I have Automator enabled for Full Disk Access.  Is there another setting?

Comment: @torpedo5, The _code_ I posted does exactly what I said it does!!! If that doesn't work for you it's because IMO your question is incomplete and lacks full details.  I can write _code_ to do whatever is necessary if the question has the necessary information!

Comment: I'm sure it does exactly what you said.  Since I don't already have a ShellScript step within my Automator script, I would benefit from any associated settings or instructions that will allow this type of step to work please.